# Lombok with Netbeans/Maven Annotations are not Recognized/Working

Tags: maven, netbeans-8, lombok

I tried to update my existing `Lombok` version `1.16.16` to `1.18.2` in `Netbeans 8.2` (maven multi-module project).

Unfortunately, all versions higher than `1.16.18` are not working. No annotation is recognized and I get compile errors in the IDE. The pure maven build is working.

Comment: [You could try 1.18.3](https://projectlombok.org/download-edge) but note that: [1] It is not a stable release. From the Lombok page: _"Download 'Edgy Guinea Pig' - the Lombok Cutting Edge build"_ [2] I didn't see anything in the release notes for 1.18.3 that mentioned fixing your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to configure the maven compiler plugin. Add the following snippet to the build section of your pom (at best to your parent pom or to each project which is using `Lombok`).

If you already have a configuration of the build plugin in your pom make sure to add the `<annotationProcessorPaths>` section.

This will ensure that `Lombok` is available during the compiling process to manipulate the AST.

---

**pom.xml - snippet**

```
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>1.18.2</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
```

Comment: May be this is obvious, but remember to add the dependency as well with the same version.